# Why does the system freeze when mounting disk images

Tags: mount, iso, kvm-virtualization, apparmor

Recently I tried to mount an ISO disk image to use with KVM. Immediately the system froze (mouse stopped, time stopped, music skipped).

I tried mounting it with Disk Image Mounter and from the terminal (sudo mount -o loop file.iso /mnt/file) and both brought the system to a screeching halt. VirtualBox was able to mount the image with no problem, but that doesn't help using it outside of VirtualBox.

The ISO image was a HFS formated mac install disk... I also tried mounting the original Ubuntu install ISO Image and had the same problem (immediate freezing).

I'm running a nearly fresh install of 15.10 Desktop, except that I've been  playing with KVM. I haven't made any major changes to anything yet.

How can I see what is causing the freeze? Is there a specific log? I don't see any similar problems on here or google.

Edit: This is the error from Virtual Machine Manager (mac.iso is owned by my user with permissions set to 777)

> Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-03-13T02:55:19.906457Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive id=MacDVD,if=none,snapshot=on,file=/home/user/Downloads/mac.iso: Could not open '/home/user/Downloads/mac.iso': Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

I've also run into my system hard freezing when mounting ISO disk images on Ubuntu 15.10. I've also been using KVM, but it's not relevant in my case.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any particular log file that explained the freeze, but I did notice that ISOs that were in certain folders (encrypted via LUKS) didn't have the problem, yet all those in normal ZFS datasets did. I traced my issue to the version of ZFS (0.6.4.2) in Ubuntu 15.10 having [a bug that causes ISO mounts to lock up the system](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3802).

After upgrading ZFS to 0.6.5.7 (via the [zfs-native PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/ubuntu/stable)) I no longer have this problem.

You don't mention use of ZFS in your question, but this answer may help those with similar issues to determine if it's due to this known bug.